# ListView Elements Not Displaying

Tags: java, android, listview, android-adapter

ListView elements are not displaying even though I've used almost identical code before. Sorry that I have to ask this type of question, but I seriously just don't understand why it's not working. None of the other similar questions I looked at were useful.

The heights of the items and ListView should be fine. Not sure what's going on. Thanks guys.

Here's the code dump:

Main Acitivity:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_select_city);
    findViewById(R.id.loadingPanel).setVisibility(View.GONE); // remove loading animation

    ArrayList<String> citiesList = new ArrayList<>();
    citiesList.add("Waterloo");
    citiesList.add("Guelph");
    populateCities(citiesList);
}

public void populateCities(ArrayList<String> citiesList) {

    // see what the list is
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),citiesList.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    // populate the ListView
    CitiesListAdapter citiesListAdapter = new CitiesListAdapter(this, citiesList);
    ListView citiesListView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.cities_list);
    citiesListView.setAdapter(citiesListAdapter);

    // listen for when a city in the list is clicked
    citiesListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            // go to the bar list activity (send the city and province with it)
            TextView lblCity = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.lblCity);
            String city = lblCity.getText().toString();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), city, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });
}
```

Here's the list adapter code (`CitiesListAdapter`):

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class CitiesListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

    private final Activity context;
    private final ArrayList<String> cities;

    public CitiesListAdapter(Activity context, ArrayList<String> cities) {
        super(context, R.layout.cityitem);
        this.context = context;
        this.cities = cities;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();
        View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.cityitem, null, true);

        TextView lblCity = (TextView)rowView.findViewById(R.id.lblCity);
        lblCity.setText(this.cities.get(position));

        return rowView;
    }
}
```

Then here's the main layout:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="com.myapp.SelectCity">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/loadingPanel"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center" >

        <ProgressBar
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:indeterminate="true"
            android:id="@+id/progressBar" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/btnBack"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:onClick="back"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_menu_back"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/btnRefresh"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:onClick="refresh"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_action_refresh"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="Select City"
        android:id="@+id/lblTitle"
        android:layout_below="@+id/btnBack"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />


    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/listViewLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/lblTitle"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp">

        <ListView
            android:background="#F00"
            android:id="@+id/cities_list"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="New Button"
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_below="@+id/listViewLayout"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Then the ListView item layout (`cityitem.xml`):

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:text="City"
        android:id="@+id/lblCity" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Edit: Looks like I'm also getting this stupid error that Android can't seem to fix (just sneaks in the LogCat):

```
E/Surface: getSlotFromBufferLocked: unknown buffer: 0xab7ccc40
```

Not sure if that's why nothing is displaying.

Screenshot: http://prntscr.com/avpy9s

Comment: can you attach the screenshot

Comment: @PhanVănLinh Edited.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `super` call in your constructor doesn't include the `ArrayList`, nor are you overriding `getCount()` to return the list size, so your `Adapter` is returning `0` for the item count, and the `ListView` won't try to retrieve any `View`s. You could include the `ArrayList` in the `super` call, or override the `getCount()` method to return `cities.size()`.

However, you don't necessarily need a custom `Adapter` for a simple `ArrayList` of `String`s. You could simply use the constructor for `ArrayAdapter` that takes a layout and a `TextView` resource ID.

```
ArrayAdapter<String> citiesListAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this,
                                                            R.layout.cityitem,
                                                            R.id.lblCity,
                                                            cities);
```

Answer (score 0):

There's no layout in the ListView. You need to add layout(Linear or Relative) inside the ListView. Like this!

```
<ListView 
<RelativeLayout />
/>
```

In the layout, you declare what you wanna show - TextView or ImageView or etc.